# How to use the magento rest api / or soap for mobile app?

Tags: api, rest, magento, soap

In magento 1.9.1.0, I have checked the rest api, seems there are some feature are missing in rest api, for example: adding the product into shopping cart, checkout. And in soap api dont have the feature login customers and access their details. please help for this any one to use complete feature of access the customer mobile app.

Answer (score 1):

Me too followed this path but couldn't get succeed yet. stuck in soap. Thinking to use rest and soap both. But still i'll need to make some custom api's for customer login and others not available.

Comment: I am also thinking that Rest and Soap don't work for mobile app.